Trouble converting RAG method code meant for Sagemaker in AWS Lambda
We're having an issue converting the RAG method to Lambda code.
We're following this jupyter notebook: https://github.com/pinecone-io/examples/blob/master/learn/generation/aws/sagemaker/sagemaker-llama-2-rag.ipynb
Here's some snippets from the code from said notebook that we're having trouble converting to Lambda:
from typing import List


def embed_docs(docs: List[str]) -> List[List[float]]:
    out = encoder.predict({"inputs": docs})
    embeddings = np.mean(np.array(out), axis=1)
    return embeddings.tolist()

s3_path = f"s3://jumpstart-cache-prod-us-east-2/training-datasets/Amazon_SageMaker_FAQs/Amazon_SageMaker_FAQs.csv"

# Downloading the Database
!aws s3 cp $s3_path Amazon_SageMaker_FAQs.csv

import pandas as pd

df_knowledge = pd.read_csv("Amazon_SageMaker_FAQs.csv", header=None, names=["Question", "Answer"])
df_knowledge.head()

df_knowledge.drop(["Question"], axis=1, inplace=True)
df_knowledge.head()

import os
from pinecone import Pinecone

# initialize connection to pinecone (get API key at app.pinecone.io)
api_key = os.environ.get('PINECONE_API_KEY') or 'PINECONE_API_KEY'

# configure client
pc = Pinecone(api_key=api_key)

pc.list_indexes().names()

from pinecone import ServerlessSpec

cloud = os.environ.get('PINECONE_CLOUD') or 'aws'
region = os.environ.get('PINECONE_REGION') or 'us-east-1'

spec = ServerlessSpec(cloud=cloud, region=region)

index_name = "llama-2-7b-example"

import time

# check if index already exists (it shouldn't if this is first time)
if index_name not in pc.list_indexes().names():
    # if does not exist, create index
    pc.create_index(
        index_name,
        dimension=embeddings.shape[1],
        metric='cosine',
        spec=spec
    )
    # wait for index to be initialized
    while not pc.describe_index(index_name).status['ready']:
        time.sleep(1)

# connect to index
index = pc.Index(index_name)
# view index stats
index.describe_index_stats()

from tqdm.auto import tqdm

batch_size = 2  # can increase but needs larger instance size otherwise instance runs out of memory
vector_limit = 1000

answers = df_knowledge[:vector_limit]
index = pc.Index(index_name)

for i in tqdm(range(0, len(answers), batch_size)):
    # find end of batch
    i_end = min(i + batch_size, len(answers))
    # create IDs batch
    ids = [str(x) for x in range(i, i_end)]
    # create metadata batch
    metadatas = [{"text": text} for text in answers["Answer"][i:i_end]]
    # create embeddings
    texts = answers["Answer"][i:i_end].tolist()
    embeddings = embed_docs(texts)
    # create records list for upsert
    records = zip(ids, embeddings, metadatas)
    # upsert to Pinecone
    index.upsert(vectors=records)

# check number of records in the index
index.describe_index_stats()

# extract embeddings for the questions
query_vec = embed_docs(question)[0]

# query pinecone
res = index.query(vector=query_vec, top_k=1, include_metadata=True)

# show the results
res

contexts = [match.metadata["text"] for match in res.matches]

max_section_len = 1000
separator = "\n"


def construct_context(contexts: List[str]) -> str:
    chosen_sections = []
    chosen_sections_len = 0

    for text in contexts:
        text = text.strip()
        # Add contexts until we run out of space.
        chosen_sections_len += len(text) + 2
        if chosen_sections_len > max_section_len:
            break
        chosen_sections.append(text)
    concatenated_doc = separator.join(chosen_sections)
    print(
        f"With maximum sequence length {max_section_len}, selected top {len(chosen_sections)} document sections: \n{concatenated_doc}"
    )
    return concatenated_doc

context_str = construct_context(contexts=contexts)

def create_payload(question, context_str) -> dict:
    prompt_template = """Answer the following QUESTION based on the CONTEXT
    given. If you do not know the answer and the CONTEXT doesn't
    contain the answer truthfully say "I don't know".

    CONTEXT:
    {context}


    ANSWER:
    """

    text_input = prompt_template.replace("{context}", context_str).replace("{question}", question)

    payload = {
        "inputs":  
          [
            [
             {"role": "system", "content": text_input},
             {"role": "user", "content": question},
            ]   
          ],
       "parameters":{"max_new_tokens": 256, "top_p": 0.9, "temperature": 0.6, "return_full_text": False}
    }
    return(payload)

payload = create_payload(question, context_str)
out = predictor.predict(payload, custom_attributes='accept_eula=true')
generated_text = out[0]['generation']['content']
print(f"[Input]: {question}\n[Output]: {generated_text}")

def rag_query(question: str) -> str:
    # create query vec
    query_vec = embed_docs(question)[0]
    # query pinecone
    res = index.query(vector=query_vec, top_k=5, include_metadata=True)
    # get contexts
    contexts = [match.metadata["text"] for match in res.matches]
    # build the multiple contexts string
    context_str = construct_context(contexts=contexts)
    # create our retrieval augmented prompt
    payload = create_payload(question, context_str)
    # make prediction
    out = predictor.predict(payload, custom_attributes='accept_eula=true')
    return out[0]["generation"]["content"]

rag_query("Does SageMaker support spot instances?")

First we deployed the Llama-2 jumpstart model, and the sentence embedding model from huggingface using this sagemaker based notebook. So now, we're doing this in AWS Lambda, we're doing the following: we imported our CSV file from an s3 bucket, then, after providing the pinecone credentials, we took code snippets from the jupyter notebook and copied over the functions into Lambda. After copying the same code from the notebook to Lambda, we had trouble with writing the Lambda handler function according to the code snippets from the notebook.
What we're expecting is a response from Llama according to the query we provided, and we're expecting the query to use the RAG method and give us a response appropriate to the document we provided the code.
Thanks for any and all help. It's appreciated.

could you please add more specific information what error you are getting? (e.g., error message, API failing, call-stack etc).
